# Nginx redirect all 403 to 404?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to get 403 responses to be exactly identical to 404 ones.

Not sure if there's a proper way to do it, but setting
`error_page 403 404`
is my current method.

Which works, but it rewrites the url to `mysite.com/404` for 403's
while regular 404's leave the url alone.

Oh and I don't have any 4XX custom pages set up and I deleted the default nginx one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/r/error_page) clearly says that if you want to change the response code, you use `=response`. For example:

```
error_page 403 =404 /url;
```

Note that making this change requires specifying a URL to serve, so you'll have to make something up.